# Synchronization of Profiles Between Stack Exchange Webistes

Tags: discussion, user-profiles, stackexchange

Is there a way that I can easily synchronize my profiles between the Stack Exchange websites?  It would be even better if I could just use the same profile across their websites.

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the faq. - Questions about the site itself are better fit on http://meta.superuser.com

Answer (score 4):

Click on your username at the top of the page, go to "accounts", look for "copy super user profile to related accounts" (I've never tried it).

Comment: I just used it.  It seems to work fine.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jim Fell: He means that it is off topic for SU itself, not for meta.